# Print a string, as if user entered it?

Tags: python, command-line, stdout, stdin

You can print to **stdout** with **Python** using `print()` and read from **stdin** with `input()`.

But how to programmatically print a string not only visible to the user, but editable, **as if the user entered the string**?

This would be helpful to ask the user about stuff while some default (or current) value is already automatically entered.

I found some questions and answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254542/how-do-i-interact-with-a-console-app-as-if-im-a-user-typing-things-into-it)) that go in the right direction, but they are all about one application interacting with another - I want to do this in a single Python application.

E.g. a `magic_input()` function:

```
magic_input('Country: ', val='Wonderland')
```

Output (where "Wonderland" would be editable by user):

```
Country: Wonderland
```